# What is this house-plant?

Tags: identification, houseplants, plant-care

What plant is it? It's dying and I don't know why!

[image: Plant: what am I and why am I poorly?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is Fatsia japonica, an evergreen plant that can be grown outdoors as well as inside. It tolerates low light levels well, but it does need cooler temperatures in winter, as well as not being at all happy in overheated rooms generally. Information on care indoors here https://homeguides.sfgate.com/grow-fatsia-japonica-indoors-70510.html.

Please inspect your plant thoroughly, preferably using a magnifying glass. I can see what look like little white specks here and there on some stems - these may be the normal specks that occur on this plant, or they may be an insect problem, I can't tell from the photo. Check under the leaves and in the junction of leaf to stem and stem to mainstem to see if you can find any insects or webbing anywhere. Otherwise, the soil in the pot looks relatively wet - if there's a drainage hole in it's pot, do you empty the outer pot 30 minutes after watering so the plant is not left sitting in water? Is there a heat source nearby, like a radiator or underfloor heating? Is it exposed to sunlight during the day? All these things won't make for a happy Fatsia...

Comment: I see webbing on the small leaf (the one in side view, with the black pot behind it), where the stem joins the leaf.

Comment: there may be a problem with spider mite infestation then - spider mites like warm or hot and dry conditions (the very things Fatsia does not like). Depending on how long the plant's been sick for, you may need to repeatedly treat,see here https://homeguides.sfgate.com/spider-mite-damage-japanese-aralia-39633.html but I'm not convinced that's the only problem its got, given the discoloration evident  at the top of the tallest stem. Might be problems at the root, or just poor environmental conditions. How long have you had the plant?

Comment: Yep. Definitely. Just thought I lend you my 20/20 vision (and good magnifying functionality) ^_^

Comment: Oh for heaven's sake, I didn't realise that comment was from you Stephie, I assumed it was the OP!